# opencart order email extra product field

Tags: php, email, field, opencart, extra

I need to add some info from cart to order email. I have to manage to show supplier field per product but I can not add it on the oc_order_product table I believe that I need that so I can send it with order email
at catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php I have add this

```
$data['products'][] = array(
                'cart_id'   => $product['cart_id'],
                'thumb'     => $image,
                'name'      => $product['name'],
                'supplier_id'       =>htmlspecialchars_decode($product['supplier']),
                'supplier_comments'     =>htmlspecialchars_decode($product['suppliercomments']),
                'model'     => $product['model'],
                'option'    => $option_data,
                'recurring' => $recurring,
                'quantity'  => $product['quantity'],
                'stock'     => $product['stock'] ? true : !(!$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout') || $this->config->get('config_stock_warning')),
                'reward'    => ($product['reward'] ? sprintf($this->language->get('text_points'), $product['reward']) : ''),
                'price'     => $price,
                'total'     => $total,
                'href'      => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id'])
            );
```

and on catalog/model/checkout/order.php

```
if (isset($data['products'])) {
        foreach ($data['products'] as $product) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product SET order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "', product_id = '" . (int)$product['product_id'] . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($product['name']) . "', Suppliername = '" . (int)$product['supplier_id'] . "', Suppliercomments = '" . (int)$product['cupplier_comments'] . "', model = '" . $this->db->escape($product['model']) . "', quantity = '" . (int)$product['quantity'] . "', price = '" . (float)$product['price'] . "', total = '" . (float)$product['total'] . "', tax = '" . (float)$product['tax'] . "', reward = '" . (int)$product['reward'] . "'");
```

The problem is that the data of the supplier is not stored on database

Answer (score 0):

better create new table for your supplier info, will be easy to manage

also as in opencart 3.X altering default database table is void

Comment: Ty for your time.